# Bootstrap Switch Dynamically Added

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying all I can to get a dynamically generated checkbox to turn into a Bootstrap Switch.

The input is generated by a function like :

```
function createButton(id) {
  return $('<input data-id="'+id'+" type="checkbox"/>').bootstrapSwitch();
}

$('#myTableRow').append(createButton(id))
```

This is a table that is constantly `.empty()` ing and re-building, so there is no time that Ican just call a generic `$('input').bootstrapSwitch()`. There's simply no logical place to put this. Any ideas?

**[Fiddle HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/gukbey96/1/)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function createButton() {
  var btn = $('<input type="checkbox"/>')
  var div = $('<div></div>').append(btn);
  div.css({
    top: -99999,
    left: -99999,
    position: 'fixed'
  });
  $('body').append(div);
  btn.bootstrapSwitch();
  div.css({
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    position: 'relative'
  });

  return div;
}
$('body').append(createButton())
```

Here is my own answer

1. Create the input
2. Create a div and append the input to the div
3. Append the div to the body far away from the visible screen
4. Call .bootstrapSwitch() on the input
5. Reset the div positioning
6. Return the div and append it where

[Voila](https://jsfiddle.net/gukbey96/3/)

Answer (score -1):

**[Update fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gukbey96/2/)**

Give all your checkboxs general class and use it to turn them to bootstrap switch, check example bellow.

```
function createButton() {
    return $('<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox"/>');
}
$('body').append(createButton());
$('body .checkbox').bootstrapSwitch();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I was hoping there was a way to generate the input, convert it to a switch, and then append it. It looks  like the only way is to append and then convert it.

Comment: Why you want to convert it first?

Comment: Because I cannot call `.bootstrapSwitch()` at some arbitrary time.